# Meme Caption Database

Tags: images, database

I am trying to create an application that uses some machine learning in relation to meme captions and was looking for a database. Is there any database or API of meme captions? If not, is there any way I could create one?

Comment: What do you mean with [meme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meme) **captions**?